# Using regular Firefox new tab page

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

I use the Tor browser for Windows and I want to use the Firefox new tab page as the Tor browser homepage  (a blank page where you see your frequently visited sites, favorites, etc)

Is that possible?